# how to match variables and values to the for loop on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import shapiro
s1 = np.random.randint(10, size = 5)
s2 = np.random.randint(10, size = 5)
s3 = np.random.randint(10, size = 5)
x = {"var1": s1, "var2": s2, "var3": s3}
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

My data is similar to this, but it's made up of thousands of variables.I want to print with the name of the variable corresponding to each value.

```
for i in df :
test_statistics, pvalue = shapiro(df[i])
print('Test Statistics for xvalue = %.4f, p-value = %.4f' % (test_statistics, pvalue))
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
Test statistics for s1...........)
Test statistics for s2...........)
Test statistics for s3...........)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `f-string`s:

```
for i in df :
    test_statistics, pvalue = shapiro(df[i])
    print(f'Test statistics for {i}:xvalue = {test_statistics:.4f}, p-value = {pvalue:.4f}')
```